# How to execute task dependency only if task is not up to date?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a couple of gradle tasks that look somewhat like this:

```
task taskA(){
  inputs.file('config')
  outputs.file('a-out')
}

task taskB(dependsOn: taskA){
  /*
   * Strictly speaking, 'a-out' is also a input of taskB, but
   * if there is already output for taskB and 'config' has not changed,
   * there is no need to regenerate 'a-out'.
   */
  inputs.file('config')
  outputs.file('b-out')
}
```

`taskB` is the actual task I'm interested in, and `taskA` only serves as a producer of intermediate data for `taskB`. When there is no previous output, it is critical that `taskA` is executed *before* `taskB`.

I'd like to be able to completely skip `taskA` if `taskB` is up-to-date (or loaded from build cache) since the intermediate data generation is just wasted time in that case. The setup above will output UP-TO-DATE for both tasks, but that isn't what I want, since when using build cache, unpacking the `taskA` cache takes a bit of time, which is again wasted.

Answer (score 1):

I've eventually worked around this by creating an external script that calls `taskA` and `taskB` sequentially, and then creating a `taskC` that has the same inputs as `taskB` and calls the script.

This essentially has combined both tasks into one, and both will be skipped when the final output is up-to-date. It works, but I'd hoped there was a cleaner way to do this with gradle.